# Qt DLL not loading (when using Qwt inside)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, qwt

I am trying to use Qwt in one of my Qt DLLs.

The thing is that the library does not load if I call a constructor of QwtPlot inside. If I comment it out it loads. Just to note that DLL builds successfully when QwtPlot is uncommented.

I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Any thoughts?

EDIT (code that loads the dll, though the code works just fine for the dll which does not have QWT inside):

```
typedef bool (*EntryPointPtr)(); 
HINSTANCE _pDLL; 
EntryPointPtr _pFn; 
_pDLL = ::LoadLibrary("..\\MyDll.dll"); 
_pFn = (EntryPointPtr) ::GetProcAddress(_pDLL, "qtLoader");
_pFn();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not load"? It crashes, gives you a message, ... ?

Comment: Just does not load. Does not crash, does not give any message. Nothing happens when I press the button that loads the dll

Comment: Could you at least show the code that loads the .dll

Comment: Perhaps throw it in Dependency Walker and see if it tries to load anything at all?

Comment: I placed a breakpoint at the entry point of my dll and it does not reach it when QwtPlot constructor is uncommented. When I comment it everything works just fine. I gues this has something to do with QWt...

Comment: I guess that Qwt's functionality also sits within a DLL? If so, does that DLL load, or might it not be able to find that one?

Comment: Yes it is within a dll. As much as I can see from dependency walker it is linked just fine...

Comment: It doesn't only matter if it linked fine, can it (and it's dependencies) all be found on the path (or from within the executable directory) at run time?  If not, `MyDLL.dll` will fail to load.

Comment: @Jasko Just to be sure, did you also profile your application within Dependency Walker. That is Profile > Start Profiling... this might reveal some of the missing dependencies later on, if there are any.

Comment: Figured it out. Seems like VS could not link the qwt library the way it was suggested by some online materials. I'll write my own experience later on so that someone else with the same problem can figure it out a bit easier. 
Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved and here is the solution for anyone who might encounter the same problem again.

Initially I set up the project settings as follows:

1. VC++ Directories -> Include Directories -> path to QWT src folder
2. VC++ Directories -> Library Directories -> path to QWT lib folder
3. Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies -> qwtd.lib or qwt.lib
   (according to debug mode)

What needed to be done is:

1. C/C++ -> General -> Additional include directories -> path to QWT
   src folder
2. Linker -> General -> Additional library directories -> path to QWT
   lib folder
3. Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies -> qwtd.lib or qwt.lib (according to debug mode)

Seems like Visual Studio could not link it properly using the initial option.

PS. Thanks for helping. Your answers guided me in the right direction and eventually helped me to figure out what the problem was. Respect to you all.